# hbs rendered site with handlebars.js in the script - nodejs

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, mustache

I use hbs to render my pages with partials for navigation and footers.

```
router.get('/test', function (req, res) {
  return res.render('test');
});
```

On one page I have template that uses mustache.js. This template doesn't work as it should as the {{}} seems to be picked up on the hbs render. Below is a basic example that illustrates the error. If I load this as a static page with express I get "Joe is a Web Developer", if I render it with hbs I get "is a".

Are there any work arounds that wont involve me changing how all my pages are rendered?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Mustache.js Inline Method</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/mustache.js" ></script>
    <script>
    var view = {
     name : "Joe",
     occupation : "Web Developer"
    };

    function loadtemp(){
      var output = Mustache.render("{{name}} is a  {{occupation}}", view);
    document.getElementById('person').innerHTML = output;
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="loadtemp()" >
 <p id="person"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

It was simple enough. I just had to escape the brackets with a \ 
So all it took was

```
 \{{name}}
```

Comment: yeah, bracket worked with the javascript code as intended

Comment: Nice! (after 3,5 years, this still works)